# How to close applications like I close tabs in browsers?

Tags: mouse

Closing a tab in firefox or chrome using the middle-mouse button is, for me, a great feature.

How can I make this work with applications in Ubuntu and the opened application panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what you can do is to enable a desktop corner in compiz to show your windows (you can do it with ubuntu-tweak) and use the middle button to close it. I know it's not the same but it's really productive.

Comment: What a great trick !
I did not know this feature and you're right this is very productive.

Answer (score 1):

I use talika applet (https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/talika) instead of windows list on gnome panel and the default behavior is that.

Comment: I Will give a look to talika, i saw that it comes with thumbnail preview too.

Comment: it shows only icons of windows, and i didn't find how to make it show titles to, that's why it is not suitable for replacement

Answer (score 1):

You can configure middle-clicking the title bar in `gconf-editor`, but closing the app is not among the options:

`/apps/metacity/general/action_middle_click_titlebar`

> This option determines the effects of
>   middle-clicking on the title bar.
>   Current valid options are
>   'toggle_shade', which will
>   shade/unshade the window,
>   'toggle_maximize' which will
>   maximize/unmaximize the window,
>   'toggle_maximize_horizontally' and
>   'toggle_maximize_vertically' which
>   will maximize/unmaximize the window in
>   that direction only, 'minimize' which
>   will minimize the window, 'shade'
>   which will roll the window up, 'menu'
>   which will display the window menu,
>   'lower' which will put the window
>   behind all the others, and 'none'
>   which will not do anything.